# XSL : replacing elements by order

Tags: xml, xslt

How I can replace elements with XSL (2.0) ?

I have two XML file, structures are identical, only contents are differents.

Example :

file_EN.xml :

```
<root>
    <book color="red" price="20€">My book</book>
    <pen color="green" price="5€" owner="Michel">My pen</pen>
    <book color="yellow" price="20€">My book 2</book>
</root>
```

file_FR.xml :

```
<root>
    <book id="b1">Mon livre</book>
    <pen id="p1">Mon stylo</pen>
    <book id="b2">Mon livre 2</book>
</root>
```

I want replace all file_FR.xml elements by file_EN.xml elements, expected results is :

```
<root>
    <book color="red" price="20€">Mon livre</book>
    <pen color="green" price="5€" owner="Michel">Mon stylo</pen>
    <book color="yellow" price="20€">Mon livre 2</book>
</root>
```

Comment: What logic links the yellow book to the book with id `b2`? Is it just the position in the document?

Comment: no, it's an ID, you can ignore it

Comment: I am afraid that does not answer my question.

Comment: What's question ?

Comment: Why does 'My book' get replaced with 'Mon livre' and not 'Mon livre 2' (for example)?

Comment: 'My book' and 'Mon Livre' are on same position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/*">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="doc('file_FR.xml')/root/*[$p]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace the text node of all leaf elements by the text from the same position in the other file you could use XSLT 3.0 and `xsl:evaluate` and `path()` as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="doc2-uri" as="xs:string" select="'file_FR.xml'"/>
    <xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc($doc2-uri)"/>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]/text()">
        <xsl:evaluate context-item="$doc2" xpath="path()"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3.0 and `xsl:evaluate` is supported in Saxon 9.7/9.8 PE and EE and current versions of Altova XMLSpy and Raptor.

Comment: I use not XSLT 3 :(

Comment: @Valeriane, well, you haven't used any XSLT at all in your question nor did you restrict the version with tags or in your text so it was worth showing a new way that XSLT 3.0 allows.